# Extracting data from blockchain using PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

I am trying to grab the total USD value of a bitcoin wallet from blockchain using cURL.  Here is my code:

```
$content2 = file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/address/1HoB5A1HBbnB3b5gQZ6U78JzA7Hqk9WWYx?currency=USD");

preg_match('#<span data-c="([0-9\.]*)">$ ([0-9\.]*)</span>#Uis', $content2, $USDmatch);

$usd = $USDmatch[0];

echo "Total USD: $usd";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backslash to escape the dollar sign.

```
preg_match('#<span data-c="([0-9\.]*)">\$ ([0-9\.]*)</span>#Uis', $content2, $USDmatch);
```